# TYPO3 frontend login always wrong user / password

Tags: authentication, typo3, frontend

I am struggling to create a frontend login in TYPO3.
I followed instructions on
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/EditorsTutorial/AccessControl/Login/Index.html
but it is impossible to log in with the given user. Always wrong user / password.

TYPO3 7.6.14

Does anyone have an idea of what else could go wrong?
Thank you, fwerre

Comment: Do you use saltedpasswords and rsaauth extension? Do you have a modified login template and if yes, does the password field has this attribute? data-rsa-encryption=""

Comment: I did anything like it is described in the tutorial. No modifications, no extensions, just the default, simple way....

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed the post is over a year old, but if someone comes around (like me three days ago :), it could solve the problem.

My TYPO3-Installation has the version 8.7.7.

---

I had the same problem and found my failure.

I deactivated the Extension **RSA authentication for TYPO3** weeks ago, just for testing, if i need that Extension (i don't know till then).

---

After i reactivated it... it works with the tutorial your linked to.

I had the same or similar Error-Message like you
[image]

In my Install-Tool -> **All Configuration** -> *Frontend (FE)* it looks like this
[image]

If you want to use RSA, you have to install the rsaauth extension.

Click the + to install RSA
[image]

Then it looks like this
[image]

And now it works like this Picture tells ;)

[image]